# how to use inserttrigger if inserting Multiple records in one insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to insert multiple records in one insert statement that time i am getting error in my trigger

error is

> `Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SetIntFlag, Line 7
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.`

my trigger is

```
declare @act char(16)if update (first_nm)
set @act = (select acct_no from inserted)
update Client set Phn9_int = 1 where acct_no = @act
```

if more than one column is inserting its showing error becoz its assigning to one variable.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that's the whole trigger:

```
update Client set Phn9_int = 1 where acct_no in (
    select acct_no from inserted)
```

Basically, my rule of thumb is if you see any scalar variables in a trigger, it's probably broken with respect to multi-row operations. The exception is if it's using cursors, but cursors can *usually* be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Declare cursor over inserted and use it, code should look similar to bellow:

```
DECLARE @act char(16)
DECLARE my_Cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT acct_no FROM INSERTED;

OPEN my_Cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM my_Cursor into @act

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
     UPDATE Client SET Phn9_int = 1 where acct_no = @act
     FETCH NEXT FROM my_Cursor into @act 
END

CLOSE my_Cursor
DEALLOCATE my_Cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use local_variable as condition in WHERE clause. Instead use simple JOIN condition

```
if update (first_nm)
update c
set c.Phn9_int = 1
FROM Client c JOIN inserted i ON c.acct_no = i.acct_no
```